# Mosquitto service does not start at reboot on Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running raspbian on a rpi 3 with domoticz.
For an unknown reason Mosquitto does not start anymore as a service after reboot.
I have to :

```
pi@domoticz:~ $ sudo systemctl enable mosquitto.service
mosquitto.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mosquitto
```

Tried to uninstall/clean/re install with no result.
Mosquito is present in /etc.init.d

Comment: Does the system _try_ to start it on boot, and does it leave any error messages when that happens? Check the system logs.

Answer (score 0):

So right after a reboot

```
pi@domoticz:~ $ journalctl -u mosquitto
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-11-03 18:16:43 CET, end at Wed 2019-07-17 23:52:15 CEST. --
juil. 17 23:51:33 domoticz systemd[1]: Starting LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker...
juil. 17 23:51:34 domoticz mosquitto[406]: Starting network daemon:: mosquitto.
juil. 17 23:51:34 domoticz systemd[1]: Started LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker.
```

and

```
pi@domoticz:~ $ sudo systemctl status mosquitto
● mosquitto.service - LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mosquitto; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-07-17 23:51:34 CEST; 1min 52s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 406 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mosquitto start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mosquitto.service

juil. 17 23:51:33 domoticz systemd[1]: Starting LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker...
juil. 17 23:51:34 domoticz mosquitto[406]: Starting network daemon:: mosquitto.
juil. 17 23:51:34 domoticz systemd[1]: Started LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker.
```